# Scope on average value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to define a scope on my Movie model in order to select all movies with an average rating higher then the provided value.

So far I have the following models:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Callbacks & Plugins

  # Associations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :ratings

  # Validations
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :description, presence: true

  # Scopes
  scope :category, -> (category) { joins(:categories).where("categories.id = ?", category) }
  scope :searchable, -> (query) { where("name LIKE '%?%'", query) }
  scope :rating, -> (rating) { joins(:ratings).average("ratings.value")) }
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Callback & plugins

  # Associations
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie, counter_cache: true

  # Validations
  validates :value, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 5 }
  validates :user, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :movie_id }
end
```

Now I'm playing around with the query options in Rails.
What I want to do is have a scope that selects all ratings for the particular movie. Calculates the average using the **value** property of the rating. And if that value is equal or higher to the provided value, that movie is selected.

As in the code i've been playing with the **joins** and **average** query options, but I'm not sure how to combine them in getting what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found it...

```
scope :rating, -> (rating) { joins(:ratings).group("movies.id").having("AVG(ratings.value) > ? OR AVG(ratings.value) = ?", rating, rating) }
```

Generates the following query for me:

```
 Movie Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies" INNER JOIN "ratings" ON "ratings"."movie_id" = "movies"."id" GROUP BY movies.id HAVING AVG(ratings.value) > 1 OR AVG(ratings.value) = 1
```

Which is what I want I think. Will test it with some Rspec now to see if it works.